# Is there a way to test my web app to see if it can handle thousands of hits from many geographic regions?

Tags: java, performance, traffic

I have a web app and I want to see how much traffic it can take without crashing.

Is there a service or a product out there that will pound on my web site with thousands or tens of thousands of hits for a sustained period from a variety of geographic regions?

Comment: Properly called web site load and stress testing tools. It is like controlling a botnet and sending it on havoc or your site.

Comment: what difference would geographic regions make to the test?

Comment: The geographic regions aspect is simply to duplicate real life usage as closely as possible.  Technically, it's probably more important that they be on different machines and different networks; but from a marketing perspective (keeping my client happy) it would be nice it there was geographic diversity as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option I have read about is to use Amazons EC2 to generate the traffic, this means you can rent a large number of machines from a few different geography's for relatively little money. You can then run up existing load testing tools as the other answers are mentioning or write your own if you have special requirements.

Answer (score 3):

[JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is a popular load-testing tool

Answer (score 1):

I have read about [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) but never used it though.